# Send a list of users by email in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to send a list of users by email. It's working correctly, however, even though my list contains 2 users, only 1 user is shown when the email is recieved.

This is how I'm filling my list. This works fine.

```
List<AccountCourse> ac = new AdminBL().GetAccountCourseByCourseId(crs.Id);
                var ListOfUsers = new List<string>();
                foreach(AccountCourse acrs in ac)
                {
                    string username = new AdminBL().GetAccountByAccountId(acrs.AccountId);
                    ListOfUsers.Add(username);
                }
```

And this is how I'm trying to fill the body of the email message with the list of users. This is what is not working correctly:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < ListOfUsers.Count; i++)
                msg.Body = "The users registered for this course are: " + ListOfUsers[i].ToString() + " ";
```

Any idea how I can fix it? Thank you.

Comment: So each time through the loop you _replace_ the message body with a new line containing one username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
msg.Body = "The users registered for this course are: " + String.Join(", ", ListOfUsers.ToArray()) + " ";
```

The `String.Join` will take the names of your users and append them together using a comma and space.  Giving you a single string for your body; your solution is replacing the body each time through the loop resulting in your email body only containing the last name in the list.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was looking for. You've made a small mistake though: It needs to be String.Join(", ", ListOfUsers.ToArray()) not the other way round, separator goes first otherwise it will throw an exception. Otherwise, it worked fine. thanks alot

Comment: @GomuGomuZoro Fixed in my answer

Answer (score 1):

actually u r not concatinating ur msg.Body,this will work :-

```
msg.Body = "The users registered for this course are: ";
for(int i = 0; i < ListOfUsers.Count; i++)
msg.Body += ListOfUsers[i].ToString() + ", ";
```